# Bonus points, only negative

Tags: phrase-requests, connotation

If you’re critiquing something, you might say that you’re giving it “bonus points” for an aspect that wasn’t essential or part of your original grading scheme, but you liked and consider to add something to the work.

Please suggest a similar phrase to use for an aspect that, as with bonus points, wasn’t essential or part of your original grading scheme, but that you *disliked* and consider to detract from the work.  I’ve tried “negative bonus points,” “bonus penalties,” and “penalty points,” but none of them sounds quite right.

Comment: I was going to suggest looking up antonyms for 'kudos', as that's a concise term for quantifiable praise. However, I haven't yet found a good list of antonyms for kudos. That said, Chris' answer is excellent.

Comment: Your students must love you.

Comment: @djechlin This is actually for a book review, not for student work.

Comment: I realise it doesn't really answer the question (hence, this is a comment) but why not just "The bad points of the article are..."?  (Here, I'm using "point" in the sense of "issue", rather than scoring.)

Comment: I can't possibly believe that nobody chimed in with "10 points from Gryffindor" usage of "points" with a "from".

Answer (score 32, accepted):

*demerits* - Marks awarded against someone for a fault or offense (definition from google).

Comment: I'm going to leave this open a couple days in case something even better comes along, but I think "additional demerits" is pretty much what I wanted.

Comment: "docking" is much better here, in the context at hand; and it has the same vibe as "bonus!"

Comment: -1 nothing supernumerary about *demerit* http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/demerit http://www.thefreedictionary.com/demerit

Comment: The word 'demerit' doesn't convey the notion that extra work was done to earn the negative points.

Comment: @DaveMagner Hence 'additional demerits' instead of just 'demerits'. But that phrase has the connotations I want.

Answer (score 15):

Have you considered "malus points"?

Comment: Like an apple for the teacher?

Comment: Not sure I understand your comment.

Comment: [Cause](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/malus#Etymology_2).

Comment: @JohnLawler More like the fruit of that forbidden tree, whose mortal taste. brought death into the World, and all our woe, with loss of Eden.

Comment: In French, in insurance matters there's a system called "bonus/malus" for establishing rates. In this sense malus is the exact opposite of bonus. I think that's what @painfulenglish was refering to.

Comment: Indeed, malus as the opposite of bonus. My thoughts were pure and nonreligious. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonus-malus

Comment: I accidentally read 'malus' as 'malleus' and suddenly thought hammers were involved.

Comment: I have to +1 for malus points just because that sounds like what an engaging and fun teacher would call it. The top scored answer (thus far) of "demerits" has a very serious connotation to it, whereas this sounds a bit more whimsical to my ear. You might choose between the two based on the audience, then.

Answer (score 11):

The phrase "I'm docking you X points" comes to mind.

"Your overall entry was satisfactory, but I'm docking you 10 points for submitting it late."

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you'll come up with a very good term that involves use of the words 'bonus' or 'points'. I would use something like 'deductions' in place of 'points' and something like 'superfluous' in place of 'bonus'. 'Deductions for superfluous content' might be a good way to label it.

Comment: +1 Deductions is perfect.  Why was this downvoted?

Answer (score 0):

What about **penalty points**? Succinct, easily understood, and even alliterative!

Answer (score -3):

The antonym of *bonus* is *malus*, so you might consider something like "I'll give you a malus for submitting this paper late".

Comment: This answer duplicates [one already given](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/186488/18696). If you like the idea of *malus*, please upvote the original answer instead of adding a duplicate.